# saving project as incremental json diffs?

Tags: javascript, django, json

I've been building a web paint program wherein the state of a user's artwork is saved as a json object.  Every time I add to the client's undo stack (just an array of json objects describing the state of theproject), I want to save the state to the server too.

I am wondering if there an elegant way to [1] only send up the diffs and then [2] be able to download the project later and recreate the current state of the project?  I fear this could get messy and am trending towards just uploading the complete json project state at every undo step.  Any suggestions or pointers to projects which tackle this sort of problem gracefully?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting - and pretty large - question.
A lot of implementations / patterns / solutions apply to this problem and they vary depending on the type of "document" you're keeping track of updates of.
Anyway, a simple approach to avoid getting mad is, instead than saving "states", saving "command which produced those states".

If your application is completely deterministic (which I assume it is, since it's a painting program), you can be sure that for every command at given time & position, the result will be the same at every execution.

So, I would instead note down an "alphabet" representing the commands available in your program:

- Draw[x,y,size, color]
- Erase[x,y,size]
- Move[x,y]

and so on. You can take inspiration from SVG implementation. Then push/pull strings of commands to/from the server:

```
timestamp: MOVE[0,15]DRAW[15,20,4,#000000]ERASE[4,8,10]DRAW[15,20,4,#ff0000]
```

This is obviously only a general, pseudocoded idea. Hope you can get some inspiration.